# FFT for data sets without any well defined frequency

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, simulations, software, statistics

I am trying to implement FFT algorithm on a data (density of particles) to obtain structure factor. The problem is that in MATLAB (and probably any DFT algorithm which is out there) the assumption is that you have a signal recorded in time and the frequency of your data would be
$$\frac{(0:1:\text{length}(\text{data})-1)}{\text{length}(\text{data})}.$$
In the structure factor you have no limit on $k$ values so can go beyond 1. When you compute the DFT of any data, the plotted results would be periodic as I observe such a thing in  my results which is not really something that you expect from structure factor. Any suggestions?

...

Edit:
Since people asked for more clarification:
I have used a mesh grid to obtain the $\rho(r)$ from my original data sets which is the position of particles. As we know the structure factor is $S(q)=|\rho(q)|^2 (1)$ or $S(q)=\frac{1}{N}<\sum_{i,j=1}^N e^{i.q.(r_{i}-r_{j})}> (2) $ which $q$ is the wave number. I have used both formulas to compare their answers. For FFT I have used formula $(1)$ which means : `S=abs(fft(density)).^2` but as I mentioned in matlab fft algorithm the k values are chosen from 0 to 1 due to the mentioned reasons. And the formular $(2)$ which is just a normal summation of exponential in terms in positions of particles. Both formulas should give similar answers. In my case I need k values as big as 6 but in FFT algorithm of matlab you can't choose any specific regions. You don't have any control over the k values in FFT.

Let's make it simple. Is there anyone or any source which have used FFT algorithm for the structure factor or not?

Comment: Can you interpolate your data onto a regular grid?

Comment: I know a lot about Fourier transforms, but I still can't tell what this post is asking. First, please clarify that formula, as it seems that the formula uses notation specific to MATLAB which many readers here don't know. Second, what do you mean that you have no limit on $k$ values? Finally, I suspect that you're confused because of the limits on the frequency parameter that come in the discrete Fourier transform... is that it?

Comment: @DanielSank: I believe (0:1:num) is MATLAB for creating a vector of length num starting at 0 and ending at 1 (not to dissimilar from numpy's np.arange(0, 1, num), though numpy will omit the 1 in its array).

Comment: That said, I agree that the question is a little unclear on the details you point out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see the physics in this question. It looks like a question for [dsp.se] to me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty if signal process experts knew physics then I wouldn't ask this question here

Comment: Personally directed comments have been deleted. The "Be nice." rule applies at all times.

Comment: Your data may not be suitable for FFT (which has several pre-conditions on the nature of the input). In that case your choices would be (a) to pre-proccess the data into a suitable form or (b) use a lslower but more robust discrete transform. Which of these is best (and how to do it) depends critically on the *details* of where you are stuck, and your current problem statement is deficient in that regard. You have presumably been staring at this for a while and are holding a *lot* of state in your head. Don't assume that your readers have that same understanding of the problem.

Comment: I already gave a reference to the use of FFT to determine the structure factor, in the context of experimental crystallography, in my answer to this question by the OP https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/416201/cooley-tukey-algorithm-on-strucutre-factor/416265#416265 which was subsequently deleted. So certainly there are codes out there. I guess that the problem is either (a) mapping the standard units of Discrete FT onto physical units or (b) whether or not to pad data with zeros to avoid aliasing. Anyway, more details would help.

Comment: I think I understand why you're confused now, but to get there, we need to clean up this question a bit. First, note that this question is *not* about the fast Fourier transform (FFT) algorithm. This question is about the meaning of the frequency indices in the discrete Fourier transform (DFT). The FFT is just one particular algorithm for computing the DFT. Therefore, this question really should not focus on or even mention the FFT at all. I submitted an edit to that effect, but OP rolled it back, unfortunately.

Comment: Second, @dmckee's comment is off base. This question is not about the suitability of the data to the DFT. The DFT works on any data that has been sampled on an evenly spaced grid.

Comment: @Daniel *"that has been sampled on an evenly spaced grid"* One of the several way I read the question was as implying that the data were not so sampled, thus the suggestion that some work might be needed before a transformation could be applied.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Ideally yes, questions like this would go to Signal Processing. However, folks on Signal Processing will likely be confused by the solid state physics context, e.g. they won't know what "structure factor" means. That being the case, I think *probably* we're best off leaving the question here. In cases where the question author can de-imbed the essence of the question from the physics context, going to other more directed specialist SE sites makes a lot of sense, IMHO.

Comment: @LonelyProf Hi thanks for your comment. By considering the physical units I still need to have bigger k values in my structure factor. I need to get to 3 or 4.  FFT doesn't give it because of aliasing. That's the main problem. As far as I looked zero padding just increase the resolution and it's not affecting min or max.